# For differentiable functions f, g:

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

For differentiable functions f, g:

$f = f(x,y)$ for variables $x,y$

$g = g(x,y)$ for the same $x,y$

What is ∂f/∂g? ∂g/∂f? Do these derivatives even make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiation is only defined with respect to *quantities*, not *functions*. What this means is that if we regard $(x,y)$ as simply being names for the first and second arguments of $f$, the notation
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial g(x,y)}$$
Makes sense, whereas the notation
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$$
Does not. Remember that a function is a series of steps, an algorithm if you like. Asking about the change in the output of an algorithm $f$ after a small change in an algorithm $g$ doesn't make any sense, however, asking about a small change in the output of an algorithm $f$ after we change a certain function of its arguments, denoted $g(x,y)$ by some small amount, does make sense. While this concept is not defined *a priori*, the most sensible definition to use is for some function $f:(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial g(x,y)}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{1}{\partial g/\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{1}{\partial g/\partial y}$$
**Example:** When dealing with the classical wave equation,

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=0$$
It is useful to introduce *characteristic coordinates* $$\xi(x,t)=x-ct~~,~~\eta(x,t)=x+ct$$
And to note that
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi(x,t)}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$$
And now,
$$\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi(x,t)\partial \eta (x,t)}=\frac{\partial }{\partial \eta (x,t)}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)\\ =\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x\partial t}-\frac{1}{c}\left(\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x\partial t}+\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}\right)\\ =\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}$$
Hence we can rewrite our PDE (using shorter notation)
$$\partial_x^2u-\frac{1}{c^2}\partial_t^2u=0$$
Instead as
$$\partial_{\xi}\partial_{\eta}u=0$$
Which is very easy to solve, i.e
$$u(x,t)=f(\xi(x,t))+g(\eta(x,t))=f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)$$

Comment: Ah right, that makes sense now. Thank you for clearing it up mate