# Transformation of Partial Derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, linear-transformations, partial-derivative

I'm trying to prove that the wave equation is not invariant under Galilean transformations but I stumbled upon the composition of partial derivatives and I'm not quite grasping why is this true.

$$t' = t, x' = x-Vt$$

But it is known that (this is the part I am struggling with):

$\cfrac{\partial}{\partial x} = \cfrac{\partial x'}{\partial x}\cfrac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \cfrac{\partial t'}{\partial x}\cfrac{\partial}{\partial t'} = \cfrac{\partial}{\partial x'}$ and $\cfrac{\partial}{\partial t} = \cfrac{\partial x'}{\partial t}\cfrac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \cfrac{\partial t'}{\partial t}\cfrac{\partial}{\partial t'} = -V\cfrac{\partial}{\partial x'}+1\cfrac{\partial}{\partial t'}$

But why is the expression like that?

So, as I understand it so far, I'm trying to create some sort of "change of variables" between partial derivatives in order to get to the wave equation ($\cfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(t, x) - \cfrac{1}{c^2}\cfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}f(t, x) = 0$). But my issue is why does the transformation have that form.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243240/for-differentiable-functions-f-g/4243347#4243347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $t' = t,\,x' = x-Vt$ it follows $f(t,x)=f(t',x'+Vt')\,.$
Then by the chain rule, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t'}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}V\,.
$$
This can be rewritten into your $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t'}-V\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\,.$

Comment: I still don't get where the operations come from. Why is the partial derivative of $f$ for $t'$ that expression? Is the first term in respect to the first parameter and the second term in relation to the second parameter? Why is it like that? I'm sorry for asking this, but I still don't understand

Comment: @ludicrous Fair enough but you should ask clearer and more formalized questions. "Second term, first parameter, second parameter" can be misleading. To answer your question why the partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t. $t'$ is that expression: note that $f(t',x'+Vt')$ depends on $t'$ in two ways: 1. directly in the first slot of $f$ and 2. indirectly in the second slot. This calls for the chain rule as I mentioned. You have probably seen that chain rule before in the form $$df(t(\lambda),x(\lambda))=\partial_t f\,dt+\partial_x f\,dx\,.$$

Comment: @ludicrous BTW the wave equation is in fact not invariant under Galilean transformations . Do you know under which transformations it is invariant?

Comment: I believe it is invariant under Lorentz Transformations! I'm trying to prove that!

Comment: @ludicrous Correct. This is how the Maxwell equations for the EM field inevitably led our grandfathers Lorentz and Einstein to the theory of special relativity.